# Error writing /home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2/tint2rc: Not a directory

Tags: files, directory, openbox

I need to edit my `~/.config/tint2/tint2rc` because the file is blank and so I don't have tint2 shown in my desktop, but when I try to save I have this error:

```
[ Errore durante la scrittura di /home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2/tint2rc: Non è una directory ]
```

Translated should be so:

```
[ Error writing /home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2/tint2rc: Not a directory ]
```

Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a file called `/home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2`, but it is not a directory.

Maybe you meant to edit `/home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2`?

If you really need a file called `/home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2/tint2rc`, move the existing file `/home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2` out of the way.

```
mv /home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2 /home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2.old
mkdir /home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2
```

But maybe that `tint2` file is some old name and the file should be moved to `tint2/tint2rc`?

```
mv /home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2 /home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2rc
mkdir /home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2
mv /home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2rc /home/alessiomtx/.config/tint2/
```